# Set up a wifi network homepage just changing the router settings

Tags: iptables, router, wifi, netgear, captive-portal

I have a Netgear Aircard router with the usual configuration options (port forwarding, DMZ, port filters,...).

I am using this network to provide wireless Internet access to the customers of my coffee shop. Is there a way to set up a homepage for my network, so that when someone connects to my network is automatically redirected to my homepage? Without changing the firmware, just changing the router settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something called a "Captive Portal" feature. If your router doesn't come with one out of the box, you have 2 options:

1. Get a router that does come with the feature, or
2. Depending on your router's model, flash it with custom firmware, like [Tomato](http://tomatousb.org/forum/t-381082/tomato-captive-portal-splash-page-redesigned) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal)

Please note that option #2 requires quite a bit of work, depends on the model of your router (some of them won't work at all) and may result in your router getting bricked. So... proceed with caution and **read the documentation** carefully!